# How to share htm text file from assets folder?

Tags: java, android

I have been using this code below for longtime till today when I tried loading some html text files from assets folder. But unfortunately, the share intents refused to work. Because i used to use EXTRA_TEXT to declare. Now that I read my files from  private static final String URL="file:///android_asset/html_files/dancerkate.html";

Please help me change this code.So it could share texts from dancerkate.html
Thank you!

```
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.share_button:
                //share Copied Text characters via other apps button
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textView.getText().toString() + "Get App here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joseph.workerbender");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via");
                startActivity(sendIntent);

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can not sent a file through using `intent` when intentType is text

`sendIntent.setType("text/plain");`

You can read your `.html` file and get the `text` inside that file and sent by sharing

```
private String getTextFromAssets(String fileName){
    try {
        final int bufferSize = 1024;
        final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);

        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        int charsRead;
        while((charsRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            out.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
        }
        Log.d("HtmlText", out.toString());
        return out.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HtmlText", "HTML Read Error: "+e.toString());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now call the method from your code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextFromAssets("dancerkate.html"));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: If i press share button, it requested to choose via options, i chose Email, but it didn't generate any texts from dancerkate.html. Please help me

Comment: Add a debug print before "return out.toString();".  Log.d("HtmlText", out.toString()); see the LocgCat, so that you can sure code reading the text or not.

Comment: You can see the demo I create on: git https://github.com/enamul-java/ReadFileFromAssets

Comment: It still gave this error, "Can't Send Empty Texts" , Please i have posted the LogCat. Thanks for helping me

Comment: please sir I'm still waiting for your guide. I am stock in here.thamks

Comment: there is no error at all in your Log. I don't know what is inside your html. May be some font related issue but no error. Do you try git example that I made for you? Did you app crash? First make a simple html in assets folder and try. so that you can understand is there any problem or not. Then try your real html page.

Comment: Okay. I discovered from your GitHub example that you used TextView to load HTML file from assets While I used WebView. That's is the problem. Please teach me how to SHARE CONTENTS with as I used TextView to load contents in my App. Thanks

Comment: Actually no meter where you loading... getTextFromAssets(fileNmae) return you text(String) inside the file. You can use this string anywhere you want. In your case, you want to share the text. so the intent relented code in second part of my answer.

Comment: Ooohh i'm sorry, it is working now. I got it wrong somewhere. This is what i should have done; "html_files/dancerkate.html".

Comment: Also, the text generated is in html format, Is there anyhow i can make it pure texts free from html tags???